# Exclude attached storage from snapshot

Tags: centos, snapshot

I'm trying to setup nightly snapshots of our VMs that exclude our attached storage. I've been looking into `lvcreate` but can't figure out how to make it pass over certain directories. Is this possible with this tool? I'm running CentOS.

Comment: You haven't really given any information.  How are the VM's stored, and what 'attached storage' do you want to exclude?  Are you asking 'how to take a snapshot of a single LVM volume?'

Comment: My understanding is that our VM (16GB) lives on VMSAN adn the attached storage (2TB) is on compellent SAN. The attached storage doesn't appear to be mounted because it starts at `/ourAttachedStorage` rather than `/mnt/ourAttachedStorage` so I'm not sure how to describe it other than "attached storage". I'm looking to snapshot the entire system while omitting `/ourAttachedStorage` without having to deattach it first. @xrobau